# MapStruct 1.3.0.Final. don't ignore non-getter-setter methods

Tags: mapstruct

I use Mapstruct and JOOQ for mapping between record-class and POJO. Today I tried to switch from Mapstruct 1.2.0.Final to 1.3.0.Final. But I get compilation errors like this - `Unmapped target properties: "value1, value2, value3, value4"`.

JOOQ generate record-class with usual setters/getters and some public non-static methods with a name like `valueN`. `valueN` methods generates for each setter/getter.

With Mapstruct 1.2.0.Final it works perfectly fine. `ValueN` methods ignored in generated mappers. Generated mappers use only getters-setters. I didn't set ignore for `ValueN` explicitly.

How I can fix this behavior in Mapstruct 1.3.0.Final gracefully? How to configure Mapstruct for using only getters-setters?

Now I see two options:

Option 1. 
Use `@Mapping(target = "value1", ignore = true)` for all valueN methods. Can I use some regexp pattern in target prop for ignore all valueN methods in single `@Mapping`?

Option 2. 
Write my own AccessorNamingStrategy

Should I just choose one of the options above or Mapstruct has any config options for returning 1.2.0 behavior maybe?

Comment: When you talk about JOOQ `Record`, do you mean https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.10.7/org/jooq/Record.html? Can you also perhaps create an issue at https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues for MapStruct? I think that we should handle this properly and maybe even offer an option to disable fluent setters more easily.

Comment: Yes, I mean generated implementation class of http://jooq.org/javadoc/3.10.7/org/jooq/Record.html.
I will create an issue for MapStruct.
And if you could add the option to disable fluent setters, it will be great too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1.3.0.Final in order to disable the fluent accessors you would have to go with option 1 or option 2 unfortunately.

If you go with option 2 then you can extend from `DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy` and then for `isFluentSetter` return `false`.

Answer (score -1):

Or alternatively..

Option 2. Use @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true) for all valueN methods.